# Multi client socket server client disconnects after first request to the server. (C programming)

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

I am trying to write a multi-client socket server and a client to go with that server, which would send server simple requests, like, current time, date etc. My problem seems to be, that I can't get the client stay connected, because after first request it seems to disconnect and request doesn't reach the server.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <time.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

void doprocessing (int sock)
{
   int n;
   char buffer[5];
   bzero(buffer,5);
   n = read(sock,buffer,4);
   time_t rawtime;
   char tim[22];
   char dat[20];
   char day[16];
   char yer[18];

   if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

   printf("Got %.3s command.\n",buffer);

   if (strcasecmp(buffer, "tim\n") == 0)
   {
      rawtime = time(NULL);
      strncpy(tim, "Current time: ", 14);
      strncpy(tim+14, (ctime(&rawtime))+11, 8);
      n = write(sock, tim, 22);
   }
   else if (strcasecmp(buffer, "dat\n") == 0)
   {
      rawtime = time(NULL);
      strncpy(dat, "Current date: ", 14);
      strncpy(dat+14, (ctime(&rawtime))+4, 6);
      n = write(sock, dat, 20);
   }
   else if (strcasecmp(buffer, "day\n") == 0)
   {
      rawtime = time(NULL);
      strncpy(day, "Current day: ", 13);
      strncpy(day+13, (ctime(&rawtime)), 3);
      n = write(sock, day, 16);
   }
   else if (strcasecmp(buffer, "yer\n") == 0)
   {
      rawtime = time(NULL);
      strncpy(yer, "Current year: ", 14);
      strncpy(yer+14, (ctime(&rawtime))+20, 4);
      n = write(sock, yer, 18);
   }
   else if (strcasecmp(buffer, "com\n") == 0)
   {
      n = write(sock, "TIM - current time\nDAT - Month and day\nDAY - current weekday\nYER - Year", 71);
   }
   else  n = write(sock, "Wrong command enter COM to see commands.",40);

   if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen, n;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int pid;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no port provided");
        exit(1);
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = atoi(argv[1]);

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) error("ERROR on binding");

    listen(sockfd, 5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    while(1)
    {
         newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
         if (newsockfd < 0) error("ERROR on accept");

         pid = fork();

         if (pid < 0) error("ERROR on fork");

         if (pid == 0)
         {
             close(sockfd);
             doprocessing(newsockfd);
             exit(0);
         }
         else close(newsockfd);
    }
}
```

Thats the server, and the client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char rbuffer[256];
    char sbuffer[256];

    if (argc < 3)
    {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }

    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if (server == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) error("ERROR connecting");

    for(;;)
    {
       printf("Enter a command: ");
       bzero(sbuffer,sizeof(sbuffer));
       fgets(sbuffer,255,stdin);
       n = write(sockfd,sbuffer,strlen(sbuffer));
       if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");

       bzero(rbuffer,sizeof(rbuffer));
       n = read(sockfd,rbuffer,255);
       if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

       printf("%s\n",rbuffer);
    }
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "after first request it seems to disconnect and request doesn't reach the server". Please state how you have determined that. Including any debug output you have collected or other debug data used to come to that conclusion. But for starters the receiving code (on both sides) is expecting strings but the sender side is *not* sending strings as it does not send the terminating NUL character. e.g.: `write(sockfd,sbuffer,strlen(sbuffer));` needs to use `strlen(sbuffer)+1` instead.

Comment: Another common mistake in the code is that it assumes every `read` call will receive exactly one message. This is incorrect as `read` makes no such guarantees. It can return after reading a partial message or even multiple messages (with the last message possibly being partially read). The code needs to handle this by calling `read` in a loop and parsing individual messages out of the message stream.

Comment: @kaylum Wouldn't that issue been taken care of by calling bzero everytime before read?

Comment: There's no loop in `doprocessing()`. It just reads one request, processes it, and returns.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed the `bzero`. But it's still advisable to send the NUL character for the second reason (and also more efficient not to have to `bzero` for every receive). The code needs to know when a single message has been fully read. The common ways to do this are to either explicitly send the length or to have delimiters between messages.

Comment: @Barmar Is it not enough, that doprocessing() is in a while() loop?

Comment: @RičardasMikelionis no, and the bzero() call is cargo-cult rubbish anyway - the result returned by read() tells you where you can insert a null, (if you can get away with null-termination because you are only transfering text).

Comment: doprocessing() is only called once per connection. When it returns, the child process exits, closing the connection with the client.

Comment: @RičardasMikelionis doprocessing is directly followed by an `exit`, so it sure is wrong.

Comment: @RičardasMikelionis Also the while loop contains an `accept` call, thus expecting a new client in each loop iteration.

Comment: Just put a while loop inside `doprocessing`. You should have two distinct `while(1)` loops: one, for `accept`ing new connections, and one for processing one connection.

Comment: @BuellaGábor Thanks, the main problem was in doprocessing.